# Possible incorrect setting of the autoincrement in SQLAlchemy Column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have these SQLAlchemy classes:

```
Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata

class Stock(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stock'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'jm_sa'}

    date = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    center = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    sku = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    qty = Column(Integer)


class StockFull(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stock_full'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'jm_sa'}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    full_date = Column(DateTime)
    center = Column(Integer)
    sku = Column(Integer)
    fc = Column(Numeric)
    stock_total = Column(Numeric)
```

when I try to get all the columns that are not autoincrement of Stock:

```
[x.name for x in Stock.__table__.columns if not x.autoincrement]
```

I get:

```
['date', 'center', 'sku'] # i.e. all but ['qty']
```

and of StockFull:

```
[x.name for x in StockFull.__table__.columns if not x.autoincrement]
```

I get:

```
[] # i.e. Are they all autoincrement?
```

Shouldn't autoincrement be True only for the StockFull.id column?

Note:
I was able to get what I wanted with this code but _autoincrement_column is marked as protected so i assume this is not the best way to do it:

```
[x.name for x in StockFull.__table__.columns
    if StockFull.__table__._autoincrement_column is None or
        x != StockFull.__table__._autoincrement_column]
```

Comment: when you access x.autoincrement  , it will access only those where autoincrement is present , i.e-date,center and sku field at Stock table

Comment: `.autoincrement` gives you whatever you *passed* to the `Column` call, so the `Stock` columns have `False`, `False`, `False`, and `None`, all of which are falsey.

Comment: `autoincrement` is `True` by default